# How to let users write private letters to me about a node?

Tags: nodes, database, blocks, 10, layout-builder

I want to let users the ability to write personal letters to me based on nodes they read while letters are stored in the Drupal database itself (no emails involved) and will include these fields:

1. **Name**
2. **Email**
3. **Phone**
4. **The name of the node form which the user wrote the letter.**

Ideally, I'd want the form to be in a sidebar block but if I can't then a node containing **75% width node** text and **25% width form** column is also fine.

Comment: I don’t know why the form must be in a Drupal block specifically but you must have your reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal's [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module is a perfect fit for this use-case. Webform allows you to attach a form as a reference to any node and when the form is submitted, Webform keeps a record of which form was submitted, and on which node it was submitted, in a central submissions view. Whether a webform sends an email is entirely the webform author's decision. By default the only action is saving the results to the database.